# website can we scrolled to the right on smaller devices, overflow-x hides the hyperlinks

Tags: android, html, css

I've made a website on (http://www.ik-ben-zzp.nl/template3) and it works all great. Now I found a problem on my mobile phone (Xperia Z3). I can pan to the right (white border) for about 50pixels, but I cant find any outgoing elements. Now if I set the overflow-x on hidden I cant move the container, but then my menu and buttons don't work anymore.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fisrt change scale to 1.0:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and CSS style in porto.css style on line 41:

```
#filter:after {
    display: none; 
}
```

p.s CSS Style is only **for mobile devices** - it can couse **bugs** in desctop. Try to do it with `@media` query

Comment: that works great, can you tell me how you found that bug so quickly??

Comment: :) Google Chrome Developers tools (F12 -> CTRL + SHIFT + M - select IPhone 4 from drop down - click CTRL + SHIFT + C -  and look through the page with this `arrow` - it will display you all blocks with margins, paddings etc. In your case - just look in write space to the right. I found there this `:after` block, that coused this issue!) Simple and fast! Good luck!)

Comment: Thanks man, really didn't know about that easy way :) Going to try it out!